# knockout JS tabs, toggle active

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I feel like I'm almost there, but I keep running in circles.I'm running 2 loops, one for tabs, other for tab contents. It's looping just fine, but now I need to make the correct ones either active or inactive on load.

```
<div id="tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <!--ko foreach: $parent.tabArray-->         
            <li data-bind="click: toggleActive(init), css: init ? 'active': ''">
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: '#' + name}, text: name"></a>
            </li>

        <!--/ko-->
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried to use this toggleActive(init) function (init being a boolean value on the object in the array), and toggling that value. Then an inline boolean conditional to decide whether this element has the css class 'active'. This isn't functioning correctly. Any ideas?

```
    var tabSetUp = function () {
        ko.components.register('MainContent', {
            template: MCTemplate
        });

        var self = this;

        self.toggleActive = function (clicked) {
         if (clicked) {
            return false;
         }
        else {
            return true;
        }
      }
    }
    tabSetUp();

//example of my array
    var MainViewModel = {
        tabArray: [
                { name: 'bob', init: true },
                { name: 'bib', init: false },
                { name: 'bab', init: false },
                { name: 'bub', init: false },
                { name: 'beb', init: false },
        ]
    };
```

Comment: Do you mean `clicked.init = false;` and `clicked.init = true;` instead of `cliked = false;` (sic) and `clicked= true;`?

Comment: no, thank you for point that out! that was a typo. clicked is either true or false. it is the value of init

Comment: um, that doesn't fix btw, just a typo thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to have a observable which stores the active tab.

```
self.tabArray = [
    { name: 'bob'},
    { name: 'bib'},
    { name: 'bab'},
    { name: 'bub'},
    { name: 'beb'},
];

self.selectedTab = ko.observable(self.tabArray[0]);
```

Then when the tab is clicked use the [click](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) binding. By default the item in the loop will be based as a parameter which in this case is the tab. Then you can use the [css](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) binding to check if the active tab is equal to the tab in the loop. $data will be the tab in the loop:

```
<!--ko foreach: tabArray-->         
    <li data-bind="click: $parent.toggleActive, css: $parent.selectedTab() == $data ? 'active': ''">
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: '#' + name}, text: name"></a>
    </li>
<!--/ko-->
```

And then the `toggleTab` function will set the active tab:

```
self.toggleActive = function (tab) {
    self.selectedTab(tab);
};
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzwh2js1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some changes in your code.

```
var MainViewModel = {
        tabArray: [
                { name: 'bob', init: true },
                { name: 'bib', init: false },
                { name: 'bab', init: false },
                { name: 'bub', init: false },
                { name: 'beb', init: false },
        ],
        toggleActive: function (clicked) {
            alert(clicked);
        }
 };

ko.applyBindings(MainViewModel);
```

When you want to bind a parametrised function to `click` you must use `click: function () { yourFunction(yourParameter); }`

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
     <!--ko foreach: tabArray-->         
         <li data-bind="click: function() { $root.toggleActive(init) }, css: init ? 'active': ''">
             <a data-bind="attr: {href: '#' + name}, text: name"></a>
         </li>
      <!--/ko-->
 </ul>
```

Example working https://jsfiddle.net/qm9ukac5/